# How to create dynamically listbox of stackpanels that contains UserControls in WPF?

Tags: wpf, user-controls, listbox, wpf-controls, stackpanel

How can one create in WPF listbox of stackpanels that contains some custom usercontrols of same type?
Listboxes and stackpanels should be scrollable. ListBox.Items are added dynamically and also UserControls to StackPanels.
I tried google, nothing like that found, only simple listbox examples with checkboxes and images.

Comment: Everything in WPF is a container and its template is customizable.  One way to do what you want is to customize the ControlTemplate for the `ListBoxItem` of your listbox.  This MSDN page http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970773.aspx shows how all the controls can be customized using styles and templates.  Most of the examples are in XAML, but it can also be done in code.

Answer (score 0):

Use ScrollViewer and ItemsControl

For example:

```
<ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
 <ItemsControl x:Name="personsColl" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Persons,
                                              ElementName=CustomPersonInfoColl,
                                              Mode=TwoWay,
                                              UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
 <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
       <DataTemplate>
         <Grid x:Name="personMainContainer">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"  />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <!-- context for reapeat -->
        <local:PersonInfo ....  />
    </Grid> 
</DataTemplate>
 </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
 <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
             <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                     <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
              </ItemsPanelTemplate>
 </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

</ItemsControl>
```

do not forget

```
<UserControl  x:Name="CustomPersonInfoColl" .... >
```

and back code

```
public partial class PersonInfoCollection : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    [Bindable(true)]
    public IList<ShortPersonInfo> Persons
    {
        get { return (IList<ShortPersonInfo>)this.GetValue(PersonsProperty); }
        set { this.SetValue(PersonsProperty, value); OnPropertyChanged("Persons");}
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty PersonsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Persons",
            typeof(IList<ShortPersonInfo>),
            typeof(PersonInfoCollection));
}
```

you can fill persons collection from other win forms or controls.